# Passing a star argument to a shell script file

Tags: shell, sh

I wrote a very simple script which `echo $1`

Content of `print_star.sh` is

```
echo $1
```

Now when calling this script `./print_star *`, it displays the first file of the folder.

How to be able to pass a star(`*`) to a shell script?

PS. I am trying to make it simple but the purpose is to pass a whole sql query (with star) to export result to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes to it: `echo "$1"`.
You should *almost* always quote variables in shell scripting; not doing so can lead to unpredictable results (as you've experienced).

> calling this script ./print_star *

This also seems wrong, you should do `./print_star \*` or `./print_star '*'` to prevent the `*` from being expanded in the shell you're calling it from.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script to add `"` around `$1`

```
[prompt] cat print_str.sh
echo "$1"
```

and call the script with `*` enclosed within single quote

```
./print_str.sh '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is quotes:

```
./print_star '*'
```

or

```
./print_star \*
```

If you are using bash, you can also do:

```
set -o noglob
./print_star *
```

Or

```
set -f
./print_star *
```

In either of the last cases, you can reset the behavior with `set -o glob` or `set +f`